# Problem in Procedure with 2 insert and pass table name as parameter

Tags: sql-server

I wrote a procedure in order to insert the same row into 2 different tables (one table for the sender of the message and an other for the receiver)

```
CREATE PROCEDURE InsertMsg
    @tablesrc VARCHAR(50),
    @tabeldest VARCHAR(50),
    @src VARCHAR(50),
    @dest VARCHAR(50),
    @contenu VARCHAR(500)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

    SET @Sql = N'INSERT INTO '+ QUOTENAME(@tablesrc)+' (src,dest,contenu,dateEnvoi,Vu) values (@src,@dest,@contenu,GETDATE(),0)'
          + N'INSERT INTO '+ QUOTENAME(@tabeldest)+' (src,dest,contenu,dateEnvoi,Vu) values (@src,@dest,@contenu,GETDATE(),0)'
    EXECUTE sp_executesql @Sql
END
```

Execution

```
execute InsertMsg 'MSG_RS_80f355a2', 'MSG_RS_80f355a2', 'RS_80f355a2', 'RS_80f355a2', 'test procedure'
```

I get this error:

> Must declare the scalar variable "@src"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You aren't passing the values of your variables `@src`,`@dest` and `@contenu` to `sp_executesql`. You need to parametrise the statement:

```
EXECUTE sp_executesql @Sql,
                      N'@srv varchar(50), @dest varchar(50), @contenu varchar(500)',
                      @srv = @srv,
                      @dest = @dest,
                      @contenu = @contenu;
```